# How can <td> and <tr> tags inside an ItemTemplate not be nested inside a table?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I read [here](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_td_tag.cfm) that a td tag must be nested, so I'm confused when I see the ItemTemplate property tag of a ListView looking like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>    
                            <td id="Td2" runat="server">      
                                <table>        
                                    <tr>          
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>          
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%#:Item.ProductID%>">
                                                <img src="/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ImagePath%>" 
                                                    width="100" height="75" /></a> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%#:Item.ProductID%>">
                                                <span class="ProductName">
                                                    <%#:Item.ProductName%>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>            
                                            <br />
                                            <span class="ProductPrice">           
                                                <b>Price: </b><%#:String.Format("{0:c}", Item.UnitPrice)%>
                                            </span>
                                            <br />            
                                        </td>        
                                    </tr>      
                                </table>    
                            </td>  
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

Does this have to do with the fact that ListView inherits from some class and implements a ton of interfaces? Or does it have to do with some aspect of ItemTemplate that I'm not familiar with? Is my source wrong or is it "just an ASP thing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your LayoutTemplate looks like but this really has nothing to do with the ListView per se but more with the HTML layout that the developer chose.  td's best belong inside a tr but these are just tags.  You can change the css and redefine however you want.  The browser will then interpret it and display it and then you get to deal with the aftermath of your choices =).

A possible way the code above makes sense is:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

This would make a single column outer table with a product heading and then each row of that table would contain your inner table (per product) above.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way asp.net has you define your controls. Once the asp.net page is rendered (converted to pure html), those `td` elements should be nested in a `tr`. You can see the output by viewing the source of the page in your browser.